# Python timeit: results cached instead of calculated?

Tags: python, caching, timeit

I am testing several different algorithms (for solving 16x16 sudokus)
against each other, measuring their performance using the timeit module. 
However, it appears that only the first of the timeit.repeat() iterations is 
actually calculated, because the other iterations are gotten much faster. 
Testing a single algorithm with t.repeat(repeat=10, number=1) the following 
results are gotten:

[+] Results for......: solve1 (function 1/1)
[+] Fastest..........: 0.00003099
[+] Slowest..........: 32.38717794
[+] Average*.........: 0.00003335 (avg. calculated w/o min/max values)

The first out of 10 results always takes an much larger time to complete, 
which seems to be explainable only by the fact that iterations 2 to 10 of the 
timeit.repeat() loop somehow use the cached results of the loop's previous 
iterations. When actually using timeit.repeat() in a for loop to compare 
several algorithms against each other, again it appears that the solution
to the puzzle is calculated only once:

[+] Results for......: solve1 (function 1/3)
[+] Fastest..........: 0.00003099
[+] Slowest..........: 16.33443809
[+] Average*.........: 0.00003263 (avg. calculated w/o min/max values)

[+] Results for......: solve2 (function 2/3)
[+] Fastest..........: 0.00365305
[+] Slowest..........: 0.02915907
[+] Average*.........: 0.00647599 (avg. calculated w/o min/max values)

[+] Results for......: solve3 (function 3/3)
[+] Fastest..........: 0.00659299
[+] Slowest..........: 0.02440906
[+] Average*.........: 0.00717765 (avg. calculated w/o min/max values)

The really weird thing is that relative speed (in relation to each other) 
of the algorithms is consistent throughout measurements, which would indicate 
that all algorithms are calculating their own results. Is this extreme increase in performance due to the fact that a large part of the intermediate results (gotten 
when computing the first solution) are still in some sort of cache, reserved by the 
python proces?

Any help/insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you didn't show the code, my guess is that you are caching  partial results and don't know it. It is also possible that your implementation is very memory intensive and so the first iteration pays the overhead of the interpreter requesting system resources that later iterations re-use.

Comment: Without code, this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the memory allocation is the problem.

the python interpreter itself holds a memory pool, which starts with no (or little?) memory pooling. after the first run of your program, much memory is allocated (from the system) and free (to the pool), and then the following runs get memory from the pool, which is much faster than asking memory from system.

but this makes sense only if your algorithm will consume much memory.

Comment: All tested algorithms have mininimal memory requirements:

Comment: All algorithms use a constant amount of space/memory. They are implementations of several local search algorithms: solve1() implements 'iterated local search', solve2() and solve3() are varieties of 'simulated annealing'.